# Returning a value of any type that implements a specific typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Suppose I have

```
class A a where
    a :: a

data A' = A' Int

instance A A' where
    a = A' 0

selectA :: A a => Int -> Maybe a
selectA _ = Just (A' 0)
```

As you can see, `selectA` is supposed to select some value whose type implements `A`. Note: The type of `a` doesn't have to be `a`, and it could be something else, e.g. `a -> Char`. Anyway, considering that `A'` is a member of the class `A`, I would expect this implementation of `selectA` to work. However, compiling this gives the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘A'’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      selectA :: forall a. A a => Int -> Maybe a
    at --
  Expected type: Maybe a
    Actual type: Maybe A'
• In the expression: Just (A' 0)
  In an equation for ‘selectA’: selectA _ = Just (A' 0)
• Relevant bindings include
    selectA :: Int -> Maybe a (bound at --)
```

My undestanding is that this problem arises from the caller of `selectA` being able to decide the exact type of `a`. I'm only interested in getting *something* that implements `A`. This would solve the problem if it was possible:

```
selectA :: Int -> Maybe (A a => a)
```

Unfortunately this is not possible. How do I get similar functionality?

Comment: The implementation of `selectA` explicitly returns a `Maybe A'`, how do you expect it to return anything else? You can define a polymorphic function that behaves the way you want if your class `A` has such polymorphic methods, like `toEnum`, `read`, etc, and you define your function in terms of such a function.

Comment: Then why not `selectA _ = Just a`?

Comment: @kuoytfouy Adding another type that implements `A` and adding a case for it in the definition of `selectA` changes nothing. I tried to make this a minimal working example, and another type would be just extra noise in the question. Also, `toEnum` and `read` function fundamentally differently - the caller is able to specify the exact type. I don't want that - the caller should only be able to access the functionality `A` and not any actual types, such as `A'`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs What's `a`? In my question it's a type, but it's not possible to return types - only values. Besides, that's not what I want. I don't want a *type* that implements `A`; I want a *value* whose type implements `A`.

Comment: @Xiyng You defined the value `a`: `class A a where a :: a`. FWIW, your code would compile with my suggested change.

Comment: Also FWIW, it might be less confusing for you if you hadn't named literally everything "a".

Comment: Based on "the caller should only be able to access the functionality A and not any actual types, such as A'" you want the type `newtype SomeA = SomeA (forall a . A a => a)`

Comment: @user2407038, don't you mean `data SomeA = forall a. A a => SomeA a`?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I originally had more letters but it was kind of hard to keep track of them all. I suppose there could have been a middle ground though... Anyway, now I see what you meant. I guess I meant the example *too* minimal, because to me, it seems like your solution breaks as soon as I add more complex class methods (e.g. of type `a -> b`). Do you think I should edit the question to reflect this possibility?

Comment: @Xiyng Yes, my solution only does what you asked it to do, not what you didn't ask it to do.

Comment: @dfeuer This seems to work, and aside from having an annoying wrapper type, it seems like a pretty neat solution. Depending on other suggested solutions, I might look into using this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In object oriented languages, it's very common to take an object of a specific concrete class, like say a `Circle`, and "upcast" it to an abstract superclass (like `Shape`) or an interface (like `Drawable`) where it will be manipulated using a restricted set of methods (e.g., `extent()`, `draw()`, etc.) applicable to that superclass / interface.

If you are trying to take this pattern and translate it into Haskell typeclasses, you are probably going to end up with a horrible design.

But who am I to stop you?

You can more or less accomplish what you want with GADTs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
```

Given the following class with two instances:

```
class A a where
  name :: a -> String

data A1 = A1 Int
data A2 = A2 Double

instance A A1 where name _ = "A1"
instance A A2 where name _ = "A2"
```

you can define a GADT that will wrap any type with an `A` instance:

```
data SomeA where
  SomeA :: A a => a -> SomeA
```

together with an instance to bridge the methods to the wrapped type:

```
instance A SomeA where
  name (SomeA x) = name x
```

and now `selectA` can return any (wrapped) type that's an instance of `A`:

```
selectA :: Int -> Maybe SomeA
selectA 1 = Just (SomeA (A1 0))
selectA 2 = Just (SomeA (A2 0))
```

which can be used through the methods for typeclass `A`:

```
test :: IO ()
test = do putStrLn $ name (fromJust (selectA 1))
          putStrLn $ name (fromJust (selectA 2))
```

Note that the GADT above is equivalent to the existential type being discussed in the comments:

```
data SomeA = forall a . A a => SomeA a
```

Using this syntax requires enabling the `ExistentialQuantification` extentsion instead of `GADTs`.

Comment: Aside from having an annoying wrapper type, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for. By the way, your last code block seems to compile just fine on my system with `GADTs` instead of `ExistentialQuantification`, at least without the rest of your code. Also, strictly speaking I'm not *quite* trying to have a superclass. Rather, I have a set of data types that are similar but structurally slightly different, and trying to provide a common interface for accessing their data due to how similar they are. It's a bit ugly but I haven't come up with anything better, at least yet.

Comment: It looks like `GADTs` plus some other extension (e.g., `RankNTypes`) will allow the other syntax, though `GADTs` alone doesn't, at least with GHC 8.0.2.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I had `RankNTypes` enabled due to testing stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to be able to have the caller select the return type of `selectA` via the `Int` argument which you currently just ignore.

Something like:

```
data A'  = A' Int
data A'' = A'' Char

instance A A' where
    a = A' 0

instance A A'' where
    a = A'' '0'

selectA :: (A a) => Int -> Maybe a
selectA 0 = Just (A' 0)
selectA 1 = Just (A'' '0')
selectA _ = Nothing
```

(Note: This does not compile - it's just "Pseudo Haskell" to portray what I think you want to achieve)

If you don't feel free to ignore this. If you do however, consider not using a typeclass `A` for that but a data type `A` which has multiple constructors.

```
data A = A' Int | A'' Char

selectA :: Int -> Maybe A
selectA 0 = Just $ A' 0
selectA 1 = Just $ A'' '0'
selectA _ = Nothing
```

Why exactly you want to do this, though, is something I wonder.

Comment: The first code snippet won't compile, since `A'` and `A''` aren't of the same type. Imagine what would happen if someone did `let (Just (A' x)) = selectA 1 in x`

Comment: I know, this is just supposed to portray what I think OP wants to achieve. But I'll add a note saying that it does not actually compile and should be seen as "Pseudo-Haskell".

Comment: Choosing the return value based on the `Int` argument is indeed what I want to do. Basically I'm trying to create a parser for a data format, where I have a (slightly different) type for each version of the format but each version has a common interface, i.e. they all implement the same typeclass. Thus one version of the format is parsed by a parser of type `Parser P`, another by `Parser Q`, etc., and I want to determine the parser to use from the version number specified at the beginning of the file I'm parsing. This approach has a weakness though, and I might not end up using it.

Comment: I kind of like this approach because it's simple and does just about what I want. I was actually thinking of it myself, but I was hoping to find a more extensible approach. Typeclasses are nice because you can always implement more instances, but you can't do the same with algebraic data types.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting an [*existential type*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type).  These are not directly supported in Haskell's type system the way universals are, but there are two common encodings:

- A wrapper

  ```
  data SomeA where
      SomeA :: A a => a -> SomeA
  selectA :: Int -> SomeA
  selectA _ = SomeA (A' 0)
  ```
- Continuation passing style

  ```
  selectA :: Int -> (forall a. A a => a -> z) -> z
  selectA _ c = c (A' 0)
  ```